# Extjs 4 crash on item hide inside FormPanel

Tags: exception, extjs, hide

I am using extjs 4. When I want to hide an element of a form, It throws the following exception:

```
ext-all.js:54640 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null
    at constructor.isValidParent (ext-all.js:54640)
    at constructor.getVisibleItems (ext-all.js:51850)
    at constructor.invalidate (ext-all.js:38511)
    at constructor.flushInvalidates (ext-all.js:38405)
    at constructor.run (ext-all.js:38727)
    at Function.flushLayouts (ext-all.js:31218)
    at Function.updateLayout (ext-extend.js:2973)
    at constructor.updateLayout (ext-all.js:32266)
    at constructor.onContentChange (ext-all.js:29697)
    at constructor.updateLayout (ext-all.js:32263)
```

The form is like this:

```
this.ReqDetails = new Ext.FormPanel({
            width: 510,
            height: 600,
            style: ' padding:5px 5px 5px 5px',
            autoScroll: true,
            align: 'right',
            defaults: {
                labelWidth: 200,
                style: 'display:block; padding:1px 5px 1px 5px;font-weight: bold',
                layout: 'fit'
            },
            layout: {
                type: "table",
                columns: 2

            },
            // listeners:{'afterlayout':function(){RequestDetailsObject.ShowItem()}},

            items: [
                ...
            ]
            ,
            renderTo: this.get("RwqDetdiv"),
        });
```

and the logic is like this:

```
var itemsToEnable = null;
                    if (enableItem != '') {
                        itemsToEnable = Ext.decode(enableItem);
                        console.log("enable items: ", itemsToEnable);
                    }
                    var win = RequestDetailsObject.ReqDetails;
                    var record = Ext.decode(response.responseText).DetList[0];
                    ...
                    win.down("[itemId=analyzer]").setValue("test");
                    ...

                    win.show();

                        if ((record.analyzer == null || record.analyzer == "") && (itemsToEnable == null || itemsToEnable.indexOf("analyzer") < 0)) {
                            win.getComponent("analyzerTit").hide();
                            win.getComponent("analyzer").hide();
                        }
```

the error occurs at this line:

```
win.getComponent("analyzerTit").hide();
```

It is worth noting that `win.down("[itemId=analyzerTit]").hide();` also has same behavior, And `win.down("[itemId=analyzer]").setValue("test");` works in the above code.

Comment: Hi there. I'm a volunteer editor on Stack Overflow, and one of the things we often do is to trim questions a bit, to turn them into technical writing as much as possible. The public archive of questions and answers is intended to be a bit more like Wikipedia than a discussion forum or a chat room. With that in mind, we remove chatty and non-essential material - the [canonical reference is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: I often post this advice: _We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened_.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because of your [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is not created. For more details you can refer this links **[SENCHA forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?292664-Uncaught-TypeError-Cannot-read-property-dom-of-null)** and **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b5g)** to understand `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null` this `error`.

You can handle this `error` at your end using following code

```
var analyzerTit = win.getComponent("analyzerTit");
if (analyzerTit && analyzerTit.getEl()) {
   analyzerTit.hide();
}
```